# Have a click: function() that fires only once in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This pulls a list of numbered id's, say 20, and should advance through them sequentially until the last record on the page is encountered. The button click event is only firing once, and not more, remaining on the first advanced to id #. My first question is if the actual click event looks right below, and if it should be modified to some other click syntax. I can supply more code if someone thinks the issue runs deeper than the click event.

```
$.get("/System/GetNextResultId?id=" + id, function (data) {
    var buttons = null;

    if (data != 0) {
        buttons = [{
            text: "Next Result",
            click: function () {
                GoToResult(data, id == lastVisibleId);
            }
        }];
    }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't attach any click handler, how do you use `buttons` array and object(s) in it?

Comment: I'm not sure about the buttons array. Wondering if this click syntax is failing, and not updating the page with the correct id. Advances once, but stuck on that same id after subsequent clicks.

Comment: Your snippet just creates an array of objects, which contain some properties. You need to show us, where this array is read, and properties in its objects are used, i.e. the code which actually attaches event listeners to elements.